# Can You Simplify this Code?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

The code below does what I need it to do, but it looks like a train wreck and still adds quotation marks around the output.  I would guess that the same result could be had in three to five lines and be quotation free.  Do I really have to remove parenthesis and white space each time I do this? Please suggest corrections?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *key = [terms objectAtIndex:row];
    NSArray *nameSection = [letters objectForKey:key];
    NSString *one = @"()";
    NSString *two = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameSection];
    NSString *four = [two stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:one]];
    NSString *five = [four stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString * definition = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", five];
    def.text = definition;
    [definition release];
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the terms and letters collections for us and what you're trying to do. Also, it appears that the last three lines could be replaced with "def.text = five".

Comment: It would be helpful (to us and probably also yourself) if you described in plain words what you want to accomplish. If I had to guess it's something like: strip newlines, parentheses and quotes from a string. Check out NSMutableCharacterSet.

Comment: The plist that it pulls from is set up with a set of arrays and one NSString in each array. I know, I know, but I only knew how to populate a TableView from a set of arrays.  All this does is display the NSString from each array into a UITextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *key = [terms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *nameSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [letters objectForKey:key]];
    NSString *trimmedString = [nameSection stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()\"\n\r"]];

    def.text = trimmedString;
}
```

You can add `\"` to `one` to make the quotations disappear. And the `definition` lines can be skipped and you can just do `def.text = five;` instead.

Comment: I tried \" before with no success, but this looks good and I will try it as soon as I get home.

Comment: I haven't tested it but if stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet doesn't work, then stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString will work with \".

Comment: It removed the last quotation mark, but not the first... good enough for what I am doing now. Thank you for the education.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a second pass:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *key = [terms objectAtIndex:row];
    NSArray *nameSection = [letters objectForKey:key];

    NSMutableCharacterSet charSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
    [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    def.txt = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameSection] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the `two` and `definition` strings are obsolete, as they are identical copies of `nameSection` and `five`.